# Definition of lim inf?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I would like to know what is the precise definition of : 
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow a} \inf f(x) $$
when $f : R^n \rightarrow R$
in my course it is written that : $$\lim _{x\rightarrow a} \inf f(x) =\sup_{\epsilon>0}\inf_{x\neq a, \mid \mid x-a\mid \mid <\epsilon}f(x)$$
But I don't really understand what represents $\sup$ here ? We take the $\sup$ of what ?

Thanks,

Comment: This definition is precise. Perhaps your question is for the definition of $\inf$

Comment: yes, I don't understand this definition... the concept behind it...

Comment: You are taking the supremum of the rest of the expression over all $\epsilon >0$

Comment: Take the greatest lower bound of values $f(x)$ for $x$ such that $x\neq a$ and the norm-distance to $a$ is $<\epsilon$, then take the least upper bound *of that GLB*, over all $\epsilon$ i.e. as the distance shrinks

Comment: yes but here we take the $\inf$ of all $f(x)$ such that $x\neq a$ and $x$ is in $B_{\epsilon}(a)$, so then, \inf of all this does not gives us a set, I am right ?

Comment: @Dicordi a value is given for each $\epsilon>0$, so you get a set indexed by $\epsilon >0$, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set $A(\epsilon) =\{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \Vert x-a \Vert <\epsilon\}\setminus \{a\}$.

You can define $g(\epsilon)=\inf\limits_{x \in A(\epsilon)} f(x)$. $g$ depends on $\epsilon$.

Then $\liminf\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = \sup\limits_{\epsilon >0} g(\epsilon)$.